# willDisplayHeaderView properties always NIL when trying to debug iOS/iPadOS Apple Silicon Mac App

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, mac-catalyst

Here's a weird one -- I finally got an Apple Silicon MacBook Pro and I'm trying to fix a few display issues when running my iOS/iPadOS app on the Apple Silicon.  For some reason, the tableview, specifically, willDisplayHeaderView view returns as Nil.

This example code crashes due to required:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let headerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    headerView.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.white
    let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 16.0)
    headerView.textLabel!.font = font
    
    headerView.backgroundView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 28, green: 28, blue: 30, transparancy: 100)
    headerView.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 28, green: 28, blue: 30, transparancy: 100)
    
    headerView.textLabel!.textAlignment = .center
}
```

This example code, no crash because they are optional but also no effect:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let headerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    headerView.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 16.0)
    headerView.textLabel?.font = font
    
    headerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 28, green: 28, blue: 30, transparancy: 100)
    headerView.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 28, green: 28, blue: 30, transparancy: 100)
    
    headerView.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
}
```

Any ideas why the running via XCODE "My Mac (Designed for iPad)" causes the header/footer view to come back as Nil?  Works fine on real iPad and iOS compile/simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "textLabel" is deprecated, this is how you need to do it for iOS 14+:

```
 let headerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        var config = headerView.defaultContentConfiguration()
        config.text = "Hello"
        headerView.contentConfiguration = config
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        headerView.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
    }
```